# How Do I insert/retrieve Data into/from a Postgres Database using Struts 2?

Tags: postgresql, database, java

I'm new to Struts 2, and I've done some exercises, but I haven't found an example that explains to me how to insert/retrieve the data into/from a database.

I know I can use `Hibernate`, but I have to do it without using `Hibernate`, so my question is how do I insert/retrieve the data into/from a `Postgres` database using only Struts 2?

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is a GIS question.  Maybe this question would be better suited for stackoverflow?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using PostGIS but I thought it wasn't necessary to specify, can this question be moved to stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'll flag it for a moderator to look at.  If you're using PostGIS and you're moving geographic data around, I guess it technically is a GIS question.  You'll probably have better luck over there, though.

Comment: I this that should be possible to use "good-old" JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the **[GeoTools](http://geotools.org/)** java toolkit project. It deals with several types of datastores through JDBC. Here's some documentation with samples:

- [GeoTools JDBC](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/index.html)
- [JDBC PostGIS Plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html)